# Tuples Vs List Vs Numpy Arrays for Plotting a Boxplot in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a boxplot for a column in several csv files (without the header row of course), but running into some confusion around tuples, lists and arrays. Here is what I have so far

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    import csv
    from numpy import *
    import pylab as p
    import matplotlib

    #open one file, until boxplot-ing works
    f = csv.reader (open('2-node.csv'))
    #get all the columns in the file
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,bytes,Latency = zip(*f)

    #Make list out of elapsed to pop the 1st element -- the header
    elapsed_list = list(elapsed)
    elapsed_list.pop(0)

    #Turn list back to a tuple
    elapsed = tuple(elapsed_list)

    #Turn list to an numpy array 
    elapsed_array = array(elapsed_list)

    #Elapsed Column statically entered into an array
    data_array = ([4631, 3641, 1902, 1937, 1745, 8937] )

    print data_array #prints in this format: ([xx,xx,xx,xx]), .__class__ is list ... ?
    print elapsed    #prints in this format: ('xx','xx','xx','xx'), .__class__ is tuple
    print elapsed_list # #print in this format: ['xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx', 'xx'], .__class__ is list
    print elapsed_array #prints in this format: ['xx' 'xx' 'xx' 'xx' 'xx'] -- notice no commas, .__class__ is numpy.ndarray

    p.boxplot (data_array) #works
    p.boxplot (elapsed) # does not work, error below
    p.boxplit (elapsed_list) #does not work
    p.boxplot (elapsed_array) #does not work
    p.show()
```

For boxplots, the 1st argument is an "[an array or a sequence of vectors](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot)", so I would think `elapsed_array` would work ... ? But yet `data_array`, a "list," works ... but elapsed_list` a "list" does not ... ? Is there a better way to do this ... ?

I am fairly new to python, and I would like to understand the what about the differences among a tuple, list, and numpy-array prevents this boxplot from working.

Example error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../pullcol.py", line 32, in <module>
    p.boxplot (elapsed_list)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1962, in boxplot
    ret = ax.boxplot(x, notch, sym, vert, whis, positions, widths, patch_artist, bootstrap)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 5383, in boxplot
    q1, med, q3 = mlab.prctile(d,[25,50,75])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 946, in prctile
    return _interpolate(values[ai],values[bi],frac)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 920, in _interpolate
    return a + (b - a)*fraction
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elapsed` contains strings. Matplotlib needs integers or floats to plot something. Try converting each value of `elapsed` to integer. You can do this like so

```
elapsed = tuple([int(i) for i in elapsed])
```

or as FredL commented below:

```
elapsed_list = array(elapsed_list, dtype=float)
```

Comment: Was about to say the same thing - basically create the array using something like "array(elapsed_list, dtype=float)"

Comment: That did it! So how do I tell if elapsed contains strings or something else ... ? Is it the `'xx'` which is a string ... ? They all look like numbers (-:

Comment: @KM, if you look at the `type` of one of the elements of `elapsed` it will tell you if it's a string: `print type(elapsed[0])` prints `<type 'str'>`; if you add the line `print type(data_array[0])`, you will see instead `<type 'int'>`. And yes, the 'xx' means it's a string, but the `type` method is explicit. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with numpy or matplotlib, but just from the description and what's working, it appears it is looking for a nested sequence of sequences.  Which is why data_array works as it's a tuple containing a list, where as all your other input is only one layer deep.

As for the differences, a list is a mutable sequence of objects, a tuple is an immutable sequence of objects and an array is a mutable sequence of bytes, ints, chars (basically 1, 2, 4 or 8 byte values).

Here's a link to the Python docs about [5.6. Sequence Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), from there you can jump to more detailed info about lists, tuples, arrays or any of the other sequence types in Python.